# Server-side support for TLS-PSK

Tags: ssl, openssl, server, haproxy, gnutls

We are looking into supporting [TLS-PSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK) for a set of constrained devices that do not have sufficient resources to do the normal TLS handshake using certificates. To that end we are looking for a TLS-PSK component, that we can integrate on our (cloud) servers. This component may be anything, a proxy, module for apache or anything else that scales well.

So far we have found several libraries that support TLS-PSK: GnuTLS, OpenSSL amongst others. Moreover, we can find several HTTPS/TLS client libraries that we can use to send HTTP(S) requests over a TLS-PSK connection. However, what we have not been able to find are server-side solutions that would accept such TLS-PSK connections. Apache modules mod_ssl, and mod_gnutls do not expose the TLS-PSK capabilities of the underlying libraries. F5 Big-IP has TLS-PSK not in its cipher lists. HAProxy does not have TLS-PSK interfaces as well. The node.js TLS library had a pull-request that became stale and hard to apply with all the recent TLS lib refactorings...

So in short: does anyone know of a TLS-PSK capable component that we can integrate in our server backends to accept TLS-PSK connections from a large set of clients?

Comment: Have you found any solution since you posted this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Regrettably not... Probably has to do with the fact that these components would need a kind of plugin structure that allows them to fetch the PSK keys from a database/file/other form of storage. We are moving into Elliptic Curve certificates. Not as low footprint as PSK, but much better supported.

Answer (score 3):

[stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) might be capable of helping here. PSK was added in 5.09

[Installation](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/stunnel.html)

/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf:

```
[PSK server]
accept = 443
connect = 80
ciphers = PSK
PSKsecrets = /path/to/psk.txt
debug = 7
```

psk.txt (chmod 600):

```
client1:oaP4EishaeSaishei6rio6xeeph3az
```

Run with `stunnel`, or set up a service